# Hyperplane equation coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I am stuck to this very simple problem, on paper, but I cannot see a way of having Mathematica giving me the coefficients of a hyperplane equation given `n+1` points in `n` dimensions.

Let's simplify this and move to 2D, where I have equations as `ax + by + c = 0`. I have tried to use `Solve` to get `a`, `b`, and `c`, but the answer wasn't what I expected:

```
p1 = {0, 0}
p2 = {1, 0}

Solve[
  (a*x + b*y + c == 0 /. x -> p1[[1]] /. y -> p1[[2]])
  &&
  (a*x + b*y + c == 0 /. x -> p2[[1]] /. y -> p2[[2]]),
  {a, b, c}
]

{{a -> 0., c -> 0.}} (* answer *)
```

Well, yes, the answer is obviously correct as `y = 0` is the solution. But I'd like it to give me only one choice of coefficients, with the free one of its choice (maybe 1?).

Is there a way of having `Solve` choose a particular free parameter as solution?

Perhaps `Solve` isn't a great choice in this case?

Comment: This is the situation where I like representing hyperplanes as determinants: `With[{p1 = {0, 0}, p2 = {1, 0}}, Det[{{x, y, 1}, Append[p1, 1], Append[p2, 1]}] == 0]`.

Comment: @J.M. thanks, that is an interesting way! `Solve` then is not suited to the task?

Comment: "not suited" is a strong phrase, but I would say that `Solve[]` does too much work here.

Comment: If `{a,b,c}`is one solution, then ALL the solutions are of the form `{k*a,k*b,k*c}` with `k` any non-zero. So (this is a standard trick with homogeneous coordinates) we can scale any coefficient to $1$ (as long as that coefficient does not vanish for all choices of $k$). So one way is to simply set `a=1`. Then let `Solve` do its magic to get unique `b,c`. And then scale all three as above. That way you have `b,c,` in terms of `a`. If you want them in terms of `b` then set `b=1` and proceed as above.

Comment: Of course, then you need to be prepared for the exceptional case when the hyperplane is in some specific position. Like in your example, when the line was vertical and `a=0=c` for all the solutions.

Answer (score 3):

The list of points:

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 0}};
```

Add a $1$ at the end of each number and look for the null-space:

```
NullSpace[Append[#, 1] & /@ pts]
(*    {{0, 1, 0}}    *)
```

In this case, there is only one null-vector, and it's `{0,1,0}`, meaning that $\{x,y,1\}\cdot\{0,1,0\}=0$ is the only hyperplane passing through all (both) points.

3D example: 3 points in 3D define a plane,

```
pts = {{2, -9, -5}, {-2, 4, -4}, {6, -8, -3}};
NullSpace[Append[#, 1] & /@ pts]
(*    {{-25, -12, 56, 222}}    *)
```

meaning that the plane $\{x,y,z,1\}\cdot\{-25, -12, 56, 222\}=0$ describes the plane passing through three points.

The advantage of this method is that degenerate cases are flagged as such: consider, for example, three collinear points in 3D,

```
pts = {{1, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 0}, {3, 0, 0}};
ns = NullSpace[Append[#, 1] & /@ pts]
(*    {{0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 0}}    *)
```

The resulting null-space is two-dimensional, meaning that there are two constraints on the points, which together define a line in 3D (not a plane): $\{x,y,z,1\}\cdot\{0,0,1,0\}=0\land\{x,y,z,1\}\cdot\{0,1,0,0\}=0$, which simplifies to $y=0\land z=0$:

```
And @@ Thread[ns . {x, y, z, 1} == 0]
(*    z == 0 && y == 0    *)
```

Comment: Thanks, Roman. This is nice, I would have liked to avoid computing the null space and using `Solve` to avoid degenerate cases by hand. I guess I'll have to do it by hand as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 4;
pts = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {n, n}]
vars = Table[c[k], {k, 0, n}]
equs = Join[Thread[pts.Take[vars, {2, n + 1}] + vars[[1]] Table[1, n] == 0], {c[0] > 1}]
FindInstance[equs, vars, Reals]
```

To avoid the trivial solution we should introduce a nonhomogeneous condition like **c[0] > 1**